# Image src with php variable does not display the image on the web page

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wrote a code which is retrive image paths and display on the website in bootstrap grid style.But it does not showing the image. Code is working fine, Please help me. here is my code

```
<div class="row">
<?while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {?>
<div class = "col-md-3">
  <?php echo $row['keywords'];?>
  <?php $imagePath = $row['video_url'];?>
  <?php echo $imagePath;?>
  <div id="video_thumbnail">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <?php echo '<img src="' . $imagePath . '">'; ?>
        <img src="<?php echo file_dir . '/' . $imagePath; ?>" height="100" width="100"/>
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `<?php echo '<img src="' . $imagePath . '">'; ?>` what's this line for?

Comment: right click inspect element on the broken image and check

Comment: ok i did it. Thank you for @Ghost. It was a path erro.Because I set the path to the /opt/lampp/htdocs/video_frames/imge.jpg but it runs on the localhost server so I set the path to /video_frames/image.jpg. Now its working fine. Thank you every one.

Comment: @tharikanikethani good, when images don't appear, always right click inspect element, most of the time its the wrong path or a permission issue to access the path and/or file.

Answer (score 0):

unless file_dir is a constant using DEFINE, I suspect it's because you didn't put a $ in front of it $file_dir

You are also displaying two files.  One with the file path and one without.

Comment: i assumed the  '<?php echo '<img src="' . $imagePath . '">'; ?>' was a debug

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, the mysql query is returning a path which is not linked .... 
ie `<image src="myImage.jpg" />` is not the same as `<image src="images/myImage.jpg" />`

As @pmahomme said, right click the element and check the pat and if need be add the additional requirements